# Shell script to start a new process but close the terminal window

Tags: scripts

I am new to shell scripting. I am writing a startup script that takes an argument and launches a process based on the argument value.

Example : I want to launch my groovyConsole located inside some directory using the starter script like this.

```
sh Starter.sh groovy
```

Inside the script this is the logic

```
if [ $1 = "groovy" ] 
then
    cd Works/Groovy/groovy-1.8.6/bin
    ./groovyConsole
fi
```

This does start the process but I see that this process is bind with the terminal window. If I close the terminal window the process is being killed (obviously). So I want to know if there is a way that running the above command will execute the script and start the process but close the terminal window?

Comment: I wouldn't add the location in the script. Instead, try defining some env variables, like export GROOVY_HOME='Works/Groovy/groovy/'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can detach it from your current process with [`nohup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/nohup.1.html) and `&`

```
if [ $1 = "groovy" ] 
then
    cd Works/Groovy/groovy-1.8.6/bin
    nohup ./groovyConsole & 
fi
```

This would leave the command groovyConsole running until you kill it.
This does not close the terminal window though buy you do that like this ...

```
sh Starter.sh groovy && exit
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert, how ever this should work.

```
if [ $1 = "groovy" ] 
then
    Works/Groovy/groovy-1.8.6/bin/groovyConsole &
    exit
fi
```

Explanation:

1. No need to CD, just run it directly with absolute path.
2. `&` start applications in background
3. exit to get exit the terminal

Comment: That `exit` will only exit the shell that is executing as a sub-process of whatever spawned the script. i.e. it won't close the parent shell.

Answer (score 1):

try change  ./groovyConsole  to  ./groovyConsole &
and add an exit after the line

Comment: Adding & allows you to run the process while keep using the shell but if you kill the shell the process will still be killed.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a shell script to close its parent process, it has to kill it explicitly.  It is also a *very bad practice to do this* (because down the road you might be running this script in an environment other than what you're expecting), but if you really want to, you can try:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $1 = "groovy" ] 
then
    cd Works/Groovy/groovy-1.8.6/bin
    nohup ./groovyConsole &
    kill $PPID
fi
```